# Can't print value get from jQuery Ajax call for Servlet

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to simply print the value which I get from Servlet-response.

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#Identify').click(function() {

                 var numberList = document.getElementById("inputString");
                 var kth = document.getElementById("nthHighest");
                 dataString = "inputString=" + numberList.value + "&nthHighest="+kth.value;
                 $.ajax({
                     url : "/HelloHalozen/HighestNumber",
                     data : dataString,
                     type : "POST",
                     dataType : "text",
                     success : function( responseText ) {
                         //$('#result').text(responseText);
                         $("#result").append(responseText);
                     },
                     error : function( xhr, status ) {
                           alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
                     },
                     complete : function( xhr, status ) {
                          alert("The request is complete!");
                     }
                   });
               });
         });
      </script>`

 <button id="Identify">Identify</button> 
 <div id="result"></div>
```

`

from my servlet I do following:
     `response.getWriter().write("You have successfully made Ajax Call..." );`

in Firebug I can see the response that I get from Servlet is "You have successfully made Ajax Call..."
But I don't see the message gets printed on the page as I'm expecting:
 `$("#result").append(responseText);`.

Can You please help me. I'm brand new to Ajax and jQuery.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `alert(responseText)`. Make sure you see the result. If you do then you know its a selector/DOM issue. If not, you know it's something in the Ajax.

Comment: I've tried that `alert(responseText)`; But I don't see anything... something flicks very fast but doesn't stay on the page. But as I said, in Firebug I can see the expected response.

Comment: A javascript alert box should stay on the screen until you click the ok button. If the alert box is empty, then `responseText` contains nothing. try `console.log('response:'+responseText);` Console log should output to Firebug.

Comment: Something is flicking..(I'm assuming thats the alert box); but thats not staying on the screen

Answer (score 0):

**Try to close your PrintWriter on the server. Maybe this can help.**

The code below may throw some light

```
String answer = "You have successfully made Ajax Call...";
response.setContentType("text/plain");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(answer); 
out.close();
```

Maybe  a complete source code from both server side and client side may help in understanding your problem.